# MySQL - Top 10 per day

Tags: mysql

I am in need to generate top 10 by `PRESENCE` & `LECTURE DURATION` from a table.

I've tried a few things but with no luck. Here is the query as it stands now.

Could I please get some guidance to get this right?

```
select 
        t1.EVE_DATE, 
        t1.CUSTID,
        SUM(t1.ATTENDENCE) as PRESENCE,
        TRUNCATE((AVG(t1.LECTURE_DUR))/(1000),2) as LECTURE_DUR
from 
        MY_TABLE t1
            left join
        (
            select
                CUSTID
            from
                MY_TABLE t2
            where
                t1.EVE_DATE = t2.EVE_DATE
            order by
                t2.CUSTID
            limit 10
        ) t3
            on
        t1.CUSTID = t3.CUSTID
where
        t1.SUBJECT= 'PHYSICS' 
        and t1.EVE_DATE >= '2015-01-01'
        and t1.EVE_DATE <= '2016-01-01'
        and t1.CUSTID <> ''
group by
        t1.EVE_DATE,
        t1.CUSTID
order by
        t1.EVE_DATE
```

Comment: Could you share with us what the things you've tried are? Saves us writing them up again for you only to find they've been already tried and failed.

Comment: Your syntax styling is inverted too, MySQL Keywords should be `CAPITALISED` and column/table names should be `lower_case` ... in a perfect world

Comment: You want the 10 most resent eve_date? or the 10 oldest?  I would suggest adding eve_date to the t2 creation and joining on it as well and ordering by it either asc or desc depending on business need.  As it stands custID is the only join criteria which will not limit the T1... Also why a left join?  If your intent is to get the top 10 results from T1, then you would need an inner join there to limit the results to the 10... eve_dates (most recent or oldest?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want the 10 most recent eve_Dates for each customer.

**untested** I'm thinking the correlated subquery will generate a result set for each customer, but I'm not positive about that.

I don't think you were limiting to the 10 records because you had no join on date.

```
select 
        t1.EVE_DATE, 
        t1.CUSTID,
        SUM(t1.ATTENDENCE) as PRESENCE,
        TRUNCATE((AVG(t1.LECTURE_DUR))/(1000),2) as LECTURE_DUR
from 
        MY_TABLE t1
            left join
        (
            select
                CUSTID, eve_date
            from
                MY_TABLE t2
            where
                t1.EVE_DATE = t2.EVE_DATE
            order by
                t2.CUSTID, t2.eve_Date desc
            limit 10
        ) t3
            on
        t1.CUSTID = t3.CUSTID
        t1.Eve_Date = T3.Eve_Date
where
        t1.SUBJECT= 'PHYSICS' 
        and t1.EVE_DATE >= '2015-01-01'
        and t1.EVE_DATE <= '2016-01-01'
        and t1.CUSTID <> ''
group by
        t1.EVE_DATE,
        t1.CUSTID
order by
        t1.EVE_DATE
```

Comment: Thank you for the guidance xQbert. I tried correcting the query but no luck. basically the query complains about not being able to find `t1.EVE_DATE`. I'm quite confused..

Comment: I know its been a year ago, but how did you sort out t1.EVE_DATE not found ?

Comment: Only thing I can think of is the "My_Table" references were not updated to reflect proper table in both places.